# Program options have sometime one or two dashes (-foo, --foo)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

In `gcc` every command line arguments have one dash. In some other tools, options that are not a single character have a two dashes prefix.

Why is there two standards, which one is the most common?

Examples:

```
gcc -MF deps.d -c foo.c -o foo.o # Single dash
gcc -dumpspecs                   # Single dash
gcc --sysroot=dir                # Double dashes
grep --recursive --only-matching foo bar # Double dashes
```

Comment: GCC is a cryptic beast to begin with, and much of its command line interface probably traces back to compatibility over the years with the initial versions from the 1980s. With most other common tools, this is about GNU "short" and "long" option styles. Try feeding that bone to your favorite search engine.

Comment: Put simply, short options are POSIX , and long options are a GNU extension.

Comment: @fd0 Well, it seems POSIX is the standard to follow while GNU is the largest consensus.

Comment: I agree. Long options are easier to understand and remember for many.